# Scala with Spark - java.io.OptionalDataException on Master when creating new SparkContext

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark

I'm trying to work with Spark and am getting an error when running a Scala script remotely.

I'm working with Spark 1.4.1, and importing this dependency into Maven to build:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

This is the simplified code I'm running:

```
package test.package

import org.apache.spark.{ SparkConf, SparkContext }

object App {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    System.out.println("Setting up Spark..")
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("HBaseRead").setMaster("spark://141.161.88.169:7077")
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)  // Error occurs here.
    System.out.println("Done!")
  }
}
```

And here is the stack trace from the logs on Spark's master:

```
15/10/08 14:12:55 WARN ReliableDeliverySupervisor: Association with remote system [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@10.212.142.148:55578] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason is: [null].
15/10/08 14:13:15 INFO Master: akka.tcp://sparkDriver@10.212.142.148:55578 got disassociated, removing it.
15/10/08 14:13:15 ERROR Remoting:
java.io.OptionalDataException
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1348)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
        at scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.readObject(List.scala:366)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:969)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
        at scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.readObject(List.scala:366)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:969)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
        at scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.readObject(List.scala:366)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:969)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
        at scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.readObject(List.scala:366)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:969)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
        at scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.readObject(List.scala:366)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:969)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
        at scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.readObject(List.scala:366)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:969)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
        at scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.readObject(List.scala:366)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:969)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
        at scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.readObject(List.scala:366)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:969)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
        at scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.readObject(List.scala:366)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:969)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
        at scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.readObject(List.scala:366)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:969)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
        at scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.readObject(List.scala:366)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:969)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
        at scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon.readObject(List.scala:366)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:969)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
        at akka.serialization.JavaSerializer$$anonfun$1.apply(Serializer.scala:136)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
        at akka.serialization.JavaSerializer.fromBinary(Serializer.scala:136)
        at akka.serialization.Serialization$$anonfun$deserialize$1.apply(Serialization.scala:104)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
        at akka.serialization.Serialization.deserialize(Serialization.scala:98)
        at akka.remote.serialization.MessageContainerSerializer.fromBinary(MessageContainerSerializer.scala:63)
        at akka.serialization.Serialization$$anonfun$deserialize$1.apply(Serialization.scala:104)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
        at akka.serialization.Serialization.deserialize(Serialization.scala:98)
        at akka.remote.MessageSerializer$.deserialize(MessageSerializer.scala:23)
        at akka.remote.DefaultMessageDispatcher.payload$lzycompute$1(Endpoint.scala:58)
        at akka.remote.DefaultMessageDispatcher.payload$1(Endpoint.scala:58)
        at akka.remote.DefaultMessageDispatcher.payloadClass$1(Endpoint.scala:59)
        at akka.remote.DefaultMessageDispatcher.dispatch(Endpoint.scala:99)
        at akka.remote.EndpointReader$$anonfun$receive$2.applyOrElse(Endpoint.scala:937)
        at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:465)
        at akka.remote.EndpointActor.aroundReceive(Endpoint.scala:415)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

It looks like a serialization issue with the configuration settings, but it doesn't look like there's anything out of the ordinary.

EDIT: Adding screenshot of Master UI.

[image: Spark SS]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue (and got the exact same exception) recently while trying to launch spark application from eclipse connecting to my standalone spark cluster (version 1.5.2). This happened because there is a conflict on library versions used in my application pom.xml and the spark master deployment where i am trying to connect.

I started getting this problem due to a recent change in my application pom.xml. I used trial and error by commenting out few dependencies and eventually it was caused due to the following entry.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I commented this out and everything started working fine. So make sure that the library versions on your spark program and spark deployment match.

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario, I have been using 
rdd.unpersist 
while still the RDD cache block where used by different thread ,But unpersist has happened
causing java.io.OptionalDataException
So i removed the rdd.unpersist code and left it to spark evict by LRU

Answer (score -1):

I can see from your simple application code

```
setMaster("spark://141.161.88.169:7077")
```

but the error msg is:

```
Association with remote system [akka.tcp://sparkDriver@10.212.142.148:55578] has failed
```

It seems to me that your **master address** is not the same...

Or check [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33024325/spark-1-5-1-standalone-cluster-exception-in-thread-main-akka-actor-actornotf/33027284#33027284) which is similar question to yours with "**Association with remote system has failed**"

Comment: The IP listed in the error message (10.212.142.148) is my PC's IP address over the VPN. It is basically saying the association with the client that is submitting a job has failed. So I'm not sure that is the issue.

Comment: I think you should make sure that the IPs stay the same or else it may cause trouble. maybe just give it a try to use your VPN address for setMaster("spark://10.212.142.148:7077")

Comment: The IP (10.212.142.148) isn't in the Spark cluster, so setting as master doesn't seem like it would do anything. I don't believe so, but just to confirm, the location that I'm submitting a job from doesn't need to be a node in the cluster, right?

Comment: Yes, submitting node can be different from any cluster node. But my experience is that if submit job from master node it is better and less trouble...